# Extract Log file value

Tags: c#, regex

How to set Regex to extract string that starts from ERROR and ends with INFO or DEBUG or WARN ignoring line breaks.
Sample of log:

> ERROR  2017/12/12 00:11:34.352  Error: {0} System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> OutboundServiceSoftFailureException: Failure executing request against aggregation service: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at ProxyAggregationService.Execute[T](ILog log, Request request)
>      at ResetChangeRequestForMAF(String mafGuid, String senderCode)
>      at HandleImpl(CleanupWorkbookRequest request)
>      at UnitRequestHandler`1.Handle(TRequest request)
>      at ExecuteInternal[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at ExecuteUnknown(Object request)
>      at InvokeMethodOnTarget()
>      at CProceed()
>      at Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
>      at AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
>      at Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
>      at AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
>      at Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
>
> DEBUG 2017/12/12 00:11:35.300 Process entered blah blah bla
>
> WARN 2017/12/12 00:11:37.300 Possible problem with some process

Tried this - no success

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(ERROR.*?((?:2|1)\\d{3}(?:-|\\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(?:-|\\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:3[0-1]))(?:T|\\s)(?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:2[0-3])):(?:[0-5][0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9])))(.*)");
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Also, I don't think you want the C#-X.0 tags. Those are for features specific to the version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it using a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) until you encounter INFO or DEBUG or WARN.

[`ERROR[\S\s]*?(?=\s+INFO|DEBUG|WARN)`](https://regex101.com/r/cG4Uqb/1/)

- Match `ERROR`
- Match any whitespace character or any non-whitespace character zero or more times non greedy `[\S\s]*`
- A positive lookahead `(?=`
- Assert that what follows is one or more whitespaces `\s+`
- Followed by either INFO or DEBUG or WARN `INFO|DEBUG|WARN`
- Close the positive lookahead `)`

[Demo](http://rextester.com/CDGABR13813)

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"ERROR[\S\s]*?(?=\s+INFO|DEBUG|WARN)");
```

Comment: This Regex r = new Regex("ERROR[\\S\\s]*?(?=\\s+INFO|DEBUG|WARN)") does not yield any results